# How to retrive the data from a nasted JSON FireBase Database using Vue.js?

Tags: json, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have one problem and cannot retrive the data from my FireBase database using Vue.js.

I want to retrive specific field message and timestamp.
Moreover, name and email of userModel.
By knowing that, I believe I could figure it out how to retrive other too.

I have done successfull with simple database.

But, after I tried to do it on my real database with nasted code using v-for and keys, it was unsuccessfull because I do not know the exact code to write inside the `<script>` tag.

Moreover, I believe this can be done with a loop, foreach and then have to concatenate to get the correct data from the field in JSON tree like the stated below?

Knowing the FireBase config, all is good setup. I can login to my call it "Dashboard".
On the dashboard, I would like to only get and display the data in the HTML `<table>` tag.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "chatmodel" : {
    "-LeZnCBPC7FvqMeIfw_Y" : {
      "file" : {
        "name_file" : "some_file.jpg",
        "size_file" : "5332138",
        "type" : "img",
        "url_file" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xmnovimarof.appspot.com/o/images%2F2019-05-11_045028camera.jpg_camera?alt=media&token=5e13c9be-b6a5-43cb-a4ed-725148d8d3de"
      },
      "message" : "",
      "timeStamp" : "1557543050279",
      "userModel" : {
        "email" : "user@gmail.com",
        "id" : "pQe9H83cxDd8hFu6bFzzt7M5YT12",
        "name" : "First Last Name",
        "phoneNumber" : "+385123456789",
        "photo_profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Tf1LtwPEmHI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAANnw/fEXJ05bKSPc/s96-c/photo.jpg"
      }
    },
    "-LeZnGUXcNhSYzZeGJWk" : {
      "mapModel" : {
        "latitude" : "46.31",
        "longitude" : "16.33"
      },
      "timeStamp" : "1557543067886",
      "userModel" : {
        "email" : "user@gmail.com",
        "id" : "pQe9H83cxDd8hFu6bFzzt7M5YT12",
        "name" : "First Last Name",
        "phoneNumber" : "+385123456789",
        "photo_profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Tf1LtwPEmHI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAANnw/fEXJ05bKSPc/s96-c/photo.jpg"
      }
    },
    "-LeZnNJL27r5NHB8gYzt" : {
      "message" : "This is a text test message.",
      "timeStamp" : "1557543095843",
      "userModel" : {
        "email" : "user@gmail.com",
        "id" : "pQe9H83cxDd8hFu6bFzzt7M5YT12",
        "name" : "First Last Name",
        "phoneNumber" : "+385123456789",
        "photo_profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Tf1LtwPEmHI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAANnw/fEXJ05bKSPc/s96-c/photo.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am a bit of confused which code should I use inside my `<template>` and `<script>` tag.

I only need to get the data from this kind database (it has more items like that). I do not need to edit or delete it.

Thank you for any advance and provided help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way is to fetch the database in the `created` hook of your component, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

You will find below the code for a simple example based on a standard Vue.js set-up. Update the firebaseConfig.js file with yoru own project configuration.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <HelloWorld/>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      }
    };
    </script>
    
    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

**components/HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div v-if="chatItems.length">
      <div v-for="ci in chatItems">
        <h4>{{ ci.messageDate }}</h4>
        <p>{{ ci.userName }} - {{ ci.messageText}}</p>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <p>There are currently no posts</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../firebaseConfig.js";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      chatItems: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    db.ref("chatmodel")
      .once("value")
      .then(dataSnapshot => {
        const itemsArray = [];
        dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          const childData = childSnapshot.val();
          itemsArray.push({
            messageText: childData.message,
            userName: childData.userModel.name,
            messageDate: childData.timeStamp
          });
        });
        this.chatItems = itemsArray;
      });
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

**firebaseConfig.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxx"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.database();

export { db };
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. Thank you for the detailed feedback. If on success, I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the same, just different database model, but also nasted one.